# What is a good way to represent command-line arguments with JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to make improvements to the [grunt-closure-linter](https://github.com/wzr1337/grunt-closure-linter) npm project (so I can actually use it in a productive fashion), and here's where I'm stuck on it now:

I want to specify a way to pass options through to the command line `gjslint` which is the driver for the Closure Linter.

```
USAGE: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/gjslint [flags]

flags:

closure_linter.checker:
  --closurized_namespaces: Namespace prefixes, used for testing ofgoog.provide/require
    (default: '')
    (a comma separated list)
  --ignored_extra_namespaces: Fully qualified namespaces that should be not be reported as extra
    by the linter.
    (default: '')
    (a comma separated list)

closure_linter.common.simplefileflags:
  -e,--exclude_directories: Exclude the specified directories (only applicable along with -r or
    --presubmit)
    (default: '_demos')
    (a comma separated list)
  -x,--exclude_files: Exclude the specified files
    (default: 'deps.js')
    (a comma separated list)
  -r,--recurse: Recurse in to the subdirectories of the given path;
    repeat this option to specify a list of values

closure_linter.ecmalintrules:
  --custom_jsdoc_tags: Extra jsdoc tags to allow
    (default: '')
    (a comma separated list)

closure_linter.error_check:
  --jslint_error: List of specific lint errors to check. Here is a list of accepted values:
    - all: enables all following errors.
    - blank_lines_at_top_level: validatesnum
...
```

As you can see this thing has many options!

The grunt task is pretty concise so I was quickly able to find where to inject this into the command line to get this done, however I'm wondering how best to go about converting a sane JSON representation like

```
{
    "max_line_length": '120',
    "summary": true
}
```

into a commandline options string:

```
--max_line_length 120 --summary
```

It's not even clear that there is any standard way to represent it with JSON. It did occur to me that somebody else might not consider it sane to specify a plain no-param argument using the value `true`.

I figure I guess I could fall back to a more unambiguous but less structured

```
[ "--max_line_length", "120", "--summary" ]
```

or some such, though that's hardly practical considering how tempted I would be to avoid the commas and quotes and leave it as a plain string.

How is this supposed to get defined?

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted my module [dargs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dargs), which converts an object of options to an array of command-line arguments, for your use-case.

Just pass it an object with camelCased keys and it will do the rest.

```
function toArgs(options) {
    var args = [];

    Object.keys(options).forEach(function (key) {
        var flag;
        var val = options[key];

        flag = key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '_$&').toLowerCase();

        if (val === true) {
            args.push('--' + flag);
        }

        if (typeof val === 'string') {
            args.push('--' + flag, val);
        }

        if (typeof val === 'number' && isNaN(val) === false) {
            args.push('--' + flag, '' + val);
        }

        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            val.forEach(function (arrVal) {
                args.push('--' + flag, arrVal);
            });
        }
    });

    return args;
};
```

Example:

```
toArgs({ maxLineLength: 120 });
```

Outputs:

```
['--max_line_length', '120']
```